# Webscoket error connection problem in bigblueutton

Tags: bigbluebutton

I just deploy bigbluebutton using amazon lightsail. Everything is working fine except audio call and video. When I'm trying to connect audio call and video call I'm getting webscket error.
I've already disable  all the firewall.

I deploy bigbluebutton using bbb-install.sh
https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bbb-install

[image]

Here is system specifications

```
ip-xx.xx.xx.xx           
    description: Computer
    product: HVM domU
    vendor: Xen
    version: 4.2.amazon
    serial: ec222835-0f97-80b8-2cbf-361289de5846
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal uuid=352822EC-970F-B880-2CBF-361289DE5846
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Xen
          physical id: 0
          version: 4.2.amazon
          date: 08/24/2006
          size: 96KiB
          capabilities: pci edd
     *-cpu:0
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 401
          bus info: cpu@0
          slot: CPU 1
          size: 2300MHz
          capacity: 2300MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm invpcid_single kaiser fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt
     *-cpu:1
          description: CPU
          vendor: Intel
          physical id: 402
          bus info: cpu@1
          slot: CPU 2
          size: 2300MHz
          capacity: 2300MHz
     *-cpu:2
          description: CPU
          vendor: Intel
          physical id: 403
          bus info: cpu@2
          slot: CPU 3
          size: 2300MHz
          capacity: 2300MHz
     *-cpu:3
          description: CPU
          vendor: Intel
          physical id: 404
          bus info: cpu@3
          slot: CPU 4
          size: 2300MHz
          capacity: 2300MHz
     *-cpu:4
          description: CPU
          vendor: Intel
          physical id: 405
          bus info: cpu@4
          slot: CPU 5
          size: 2300MHz
          capacity: 2300MHz
     *-cpu:5
          description: CPU
          vendor: Intel
          physical id: 406
          bus info: cpu@5
          slot: CPU 6
          size: 2300MHz
          capacity: 2300MHz
     *-cpu:6
          description: CPU
          vendor: Intel
          physical id: 407
          bus info: cpu@6
          slot: CPU 7
          size: 2300MHz
          capacity: 2300MHz
     *-cpu:7
          description: CPU
          vendor: Intel
          physical id: 408
          bus info: cpu@7
          slot: CPU 8
          size: 2300MHz
          capacity: 2300MHz
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 1000
          size: 32GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM RAM
             physical id: 0
             slot: DIMM 0
             size: 16GiB
             width: 64 bits
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM RAM
             physical id: 1
             slot: DIMM 1
             size: 16GiB
             width: 64 bits
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma]
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: 82371SB PIIX3 IDE [Natoma/Triton II]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ide isa_compatibility_mode-only_controller__supports_bus_mastering bus_master
             configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=64
             resources: irq:0 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:c100(size=16)
        *-bridge UNCLAIMED
             description: Bridge
             product: 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.3
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bridge bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-display UNCLAIMED
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: GD 5446
             vendor: Cirrus Logic
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f0000000-f1ffffff memory:f3000000-f3000fff
        *-generic
             description: Unassigned class
             product: Xen Platform Device
             vendor: XenSource, Inc.
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master
             configuration: driver=xen-platform-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:28 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f2000000-f2ffffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 02:0c:36:8d:8e:60
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=vif ip=172.26.9.115 link=yes multicast=yes
```

After searching here and there i found this one,  But i'm also not sure weather this one works properly or not.
https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/issues/2628#issuecomment-635107717

What is difference between single colon and double colon in this file
`WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini`

I'm also little bit confused about some of the terminology used here like internal ip and external ip.
and
`stunServerAddress=64.233.177.127 stunServerPort=19302 Just copy from github.`
What kind of ip shoud i use here, internal ip or external ip.
`

Answer (score 1):

Check /opt/freeswitch/etc/freeswitch/sip_profiles/external.xml settings firstly.
if your binding is like that:

```
ws-binding: :5066
wss-binding: :7443
```

change it to like this:

```
ws-binding: your_external_ip_address:5066
wss-binding: your_external_ip_address:7443
```

Your external ip address is same with external_sip_ip address.

Then dont forget to restart bbb (bbb-conf --restart)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this problem has arisen from a firewall issue, Check your firewall and be sure that UDP traffic can pass over the firewall.